# UIImage from UIImagePickerController orientation issue

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm using `UIImagePickerController` to fetch images from the user's photo library and/or taken with the camera.  Works great.

I'm noticing that fetched images are often (always?) coming back with their `imageOrientation` set to `UIImageOrientationRight`.  But the image was captured with the device in portrait orientation.  **Why is this?**  This is an iPhone4S, iOS6, using the rear camera - so the resolution is 8MP.

In the simulator, grabbing photos from the photo library, images come back `UIImageOrientationUp`.

When I display the image in a `UIImageView` the orientation looks correct (portrait/up).  But when I go to crop the image the coordinate system isn't what I would expect.  0,0 is in the upper-right of the image, which I guess makes sense when it reports `UIImageOrientationRight`.

I'm looking for an explanation of what's going on and the correct approach to dealing with the odd coordinate system.

**EDIT**:  it sure appears to me that, on iPhone4S at least, the camera always takes UIImageOrientationRight/"landscape" images, and that UIImageView is respecting the imageOrientation on display.  However, if I save the image using UIImagePNGRepresentation the orientation is not preserved (I think I read about this somewhere.)

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with the orientation the phone was in when the image was taken. The phone doesn't rotate the image data from the camera sensor to make up in the image be up but instead sets the imageOrientation and then UIImage will take care of rendering things the right way.

When you try and crop, you typically change the image to be a CGImage and that loses the orientation information so suddenly you get the image with a strange orientation.

There are several categories on UIImage that you can get that will perform image cropping while taking imageOrientation into account.

Have a look at [link](http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/) or [link](https://github.com/mbcharbonneau/UIImage-Categories)

Comment: Yes, but the phone was in portrait orientation when the image was taken.  So shouldn't the image be UIImageOrientationUp?  Why is it UIImageOritentationRight?

Comment: I'm beginning to understand that the camera always produces images that are wider than they are tall (iPhone4S camera).  If the device is in portrait mode then the image is marked UIImageOrientationRight to make the image display in portrait.  If the device is in landscape then the image is marked UIImageOrientationUp.

Comment: According to [this](https://devforums.apple.com/message/301160#301160) the native orientation of the camera is landscape and not portrait.